# Captivate & SCORM

Tags: scorm, scorm2004, scorm1.2, adobe-captivate

I have published a sample SCORM 2004 and SCORM 1.2 file from Captivate (for HTML5 not SWF). I load the index_scorm.html inside an iframe to use it like a popup. How can I get the quiz/completion value from this index_scorm.html file?

Are you supposed to modify the index_scorm.html file itself, handled from iframe code or something else?

The documentation around wrappers and API is not clear on connecting to published sources.

Any help or link to resources appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a SCORM Runtime API needed which tracks the student attempt.  I do not know of a free one.  There are some stand-alone examples floating around the web but if you were to roll your own you’d need to read up on the SCORM RTE.

There is more info on https://github.com/cybercussion/SCOBot

Comment: Thanks Mark. Am I correct in saying that the html generated from Captivate is moreso just a preview file and you can roll your own html file and load the SCORM content instead? The SCORM content is actually just made up of the manifest files and XML files?

Comment: Right often people refer to the IFRAME or pop up as a LMS Player.  I’ve also heard it called a Lesson Player or viewer.  SCORM is meant to locate the LMS API Rumtime and communicate that way.  So Captivate is mainly the Quiz, Presentation or activity and the LMS is the way you get to it in a managed way.